# Dynamic content in Add-in command with ribbon dropdown menu

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to display dynamic content in a ribbon dropdown menu with [Add-in Commands](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook)? I think this is not achievable at the time of the writing. In addition, if the items themselves cannot be dynamic is it possible to have at least dynamic strings for the displayed labels.

See [image]

**Edit:**
I have created a UserVoice feature request for this [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/13225365-support-dynamic-content-in-add-in-commands-ribbon)

Note: this question is only for the new generation of web add-ins (office.js) not VSTO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently supported but It's on our plan. 
Thanks for being creative with our new features :)

Comment: hey, @nimatra! any updates on this one?

Comment: I'm no longer @microsoft