# Dynamic menu change in Office add-in

Tags: office365, office-js

I am creating an Office add-in for Word using office.js and I was wondering how I can change the buttons in my custom tab once the add-in is running.

My thinking is that it is defined in the manifest so it might not be possible, but on the other hand it would make a lot of sense to be able to do this. 
Possible after a add-in restart (if there is such a thing).

My scenario is that a user changes some settings and after saving the settings the buttons in the custom tab updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 30th, "not currently supported but It's on our plan" according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315571/dynamic-content-in-add-in-command-with-ribbon-dropdown-menu) by someone from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Weird how I did not find that thread in my searches and in stackoverflows suggestions.