# Office 365 Add-In Change banner button's text

Tags: javascript, xml, office365

I'm working on an XML/JS Add-In for Office 365, and I'm wondering if it's possible to change the text on buttons that your add-in adds to the banner.

Inside the XML manifest file, I specify a new tab to be created on the banner, and inside I specify buttons to create on that tab. The text displayed under those buttons is hardcoded in the XML manifest. Is there anyway to change, or even hide, those buttons with JS after the manifest has been imported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic content in Add-in command with ribbon dropdown menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315571/dynamic-content-in-add-in-command-with-ribbon-dropdown-menu)

Comment: No, the article listed is wondering if you can dynamically change menu drop down options in an add-in. I'm wondering about buttons on the ribbon that aren't a menu drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality is not currently available. I suggest that you submit feedback to [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) to voice your feature request.

Comment: This feature has already been submitted in Office Dev User Voice [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/13225365-support-dynamic-content-in-add-in-commands-ribbon).

Comment: Thank you for submitting the feature request Benoit. The product owners are aware of this feature request. Thank you! Future readers, if this feature is important to you, please follow the link provided by Benoit and vote on the feature.